# How can I send parameter with getters in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I want send id with $route.params.id in getters but it does not work!

In my component I have blogs object; I want save this.$route.params.id in `blogId` and then pass it with my getters method like this:

```js
created() {
  const blogId = this.$route.params.id;
  console.log(blogId); ////1
  this.blog=this.$store.getters.getBlogById(blogId);
  console.log(this.blog);
},
```

but
`console.log(this.blog)` is undefined

when I send a number like this:

`$store.getters.getBlogById(2)`

it works and `console.log(this.blog)` print my object

What should I do?

my getters:

```js
const getters = {
  allBlogs: state => state.blogs,
  getBlogById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.blogs.find(blog => blog.id == id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your getter?

Comment: const getters = {
    allBlogs: state => state.blogs,
    getBlogById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.blogs.find(blog => blog.id === id)
    }
}

Comment: Are you certain you have an item in `state.blogs` where `id === 1`? `.find` will return `undefined` if it doesn't find an item in the array that matches the condition.

Comment: yes yes , i am sure

Comment: What if you do `console.log(this.$store.getters.allBlogs())` under `console.log(blogId)`?

Comment: i get this error
this.$store.getters.allBlogs is not a function

Comment: Is your module namespaced?

Comment: Sorry try `this.$store.getters.allBlogs` (without parens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const blogId = this.$route.params.id` - is a string, and in getter your are using `===`, I think that's the reason.

Comment: why `===` not works in getters but `==` works?

Comment: Because blogId from route is a string and blog.id in getter is a number. That's why '===' operator returns false but '==' operator returns true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality